# Different C/C++ libraries crashing each other; possible interference with poll() and select()?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, camera

## Tl;dr

Somehow asynchronous callbacks from one library are showing up in the stack of calls from another library even though they are not directly talking to each other.  The crash happens when one library is calling `select` while the other has three threads calling `poll`.

## Summary

I have a project that relies on features of two third-party libraries.  Both of them work fine in isolation, but when I put them both in the same program it's full of segfaults.  The thing is, they are not calling each other directly, yet somehow the stack shows that they are.  Both rely on threading and/or asynchronous callbacks.

## The goal

I am trying to read out a USB camera using the closed source C++ [Basler Pylon API](https://www.baslerweb.com/en/products/software/basler-pylon-camera-software-suite/) . With this library, you 
- connect to a physical camera by instantiating an `InstantCamera` object.
- You can then call `InstantCamera::StartGrabbing()` to start a new thread that continuously downloads images to an internal FIFO buffer.
- Finally, you call `InstantCamera::RetrieveResult(int timeout, CGrabResultPtr& grabResult)` to put the next image from the queue into the CGrabResultPtr, which is a smart pointer object.  This call blocks idly for `timeout` ms if there is no image ready yet.

I'm trying to connect this to a larger scientific data acquisition system with many other instruments communicating by the open-source C [MIDAS data acquisition framework](https://midas.triumf.ca/MidasWiki/index.php/Main_Page). As I've currently written it, the MIDAS client program that is supposed to read the camera images does:
- On startup, instantiate a new `InstantCamera` object and verify that we can get a single image from it. 
- Go into the idle loop, which calls a MIDAS built-in function [`cm-yield`](https://daq.triumf.ca/~daqweb/doc/midas-devel/html/group__msectionh.html#gae234f64a7143ed2be1019e53613a6e85), which checks if any messages have been received, then idly waits for some timeout for an RPC call.

## The problem

The MIDAS idle loop is 100% internal, and yet if the camera has ever been read out, it causes segfaults.  A typical backtrace looks like:

```
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f6de275a277 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)>    
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56    return INLINE_SYSCALL (tgkill, 3, pid, selftid, sig);

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f6de275a277 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007f6de275b968 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:90
#2  0x00007f6de30697d5 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() ()
    at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
#3  0x00007f6de3067746 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) (handler=    <optimized out>) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:38
#4  0x00007f6de3067773 in std::terminate() ()
    at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:48
#5  0x00007f6de3067993 in __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw(void*, std::type_info*, void (*)(void*)) (obj=0x230e110, tinfo=0x7f6de6da58f0 <typeinfo for GenICam_3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0::RuntimeException>, dest=0x7f6de6afdd6e <GenICam_3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0::RuntimeException::~RuntimeException()>)
    at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:87
#6  0x00007f6de6b38421 in Pylon::WaitObjectEx::Signal() ()
    at /opt/pylon5/lib64/libpylonbase-5.0.12.so
#7  0x00007f6de6fd26d0 in <signal handler called> () at /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x00007f6de2819c73 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#9  0x0000000000434ebe in ss_suspend (millisec=millisec@entry=100,     msg=msg@entry=0) at src/system.c:4075
#10 0x0000000000431855 in cm_yield (millisec=millisec@entry=100)
    at src/midas.c:5041
#11 0x0000000000417d77 in scheduler () at src/mfe.c:2564
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#12 0x000000000040f67c in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>)
    at src/mfe.c:2899
```

As you can see, the MIDAS-internal idle loop is being crashed by a Pylon function, even though they are not communicating at all at this point in the program.  A backtrace of all threads shows the main idle loop and 3 pylon-related threads all in the `poll()` function.

I know nothing about `poll` and `select` other than they are related to each other and have something to do with idly blocking while waiting for data available.  They sure seem suspicious here.

## The Question

How can I figure out what these libraries are doing to each other that's causing so many problems?  Or perhaps more to the point, is there some way to isolate these libraries/calls so they stop interfering?

I have access to the MIDAS source (the idle loop calling `select`) but not the pylon (3 threads calling `poll`) code.  Editing the MIDAS source for debugging purposes is fine, but I'd like to avoid forking it if possible (unless it's a true bug that should be passed upstream).

Comment: Looks like `Pylon` is setting up a signal handler ( which is not a good idea in library code ), that gets triggered while MIDAS is inside `select`. The actual signal is probably irrelevant (probably SIGCHLD).

Comment: Couldn't you split your application into two (three?) processes, each using one of the libraries and then communicate/synchronize between the two (or a third "master") processes using some non-thread IPC mechanism (like pipe's, shared memory, UNIX domain socket or similar)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Probably...but I am implementing the camera readout as a MIDAS client because it does all of that for me.  There is a master MIDAS process that handles synchronization, with notifications being passed to and from clients by RPC calls and data passed by shared memory buffers.  My knowledge of inter-process communication is near zero and I would really like to avoid that road if I can

Comment: @sbabbi so you're saying the actual call to `select` may not be triggering the problem, that's just where the stack happens to be waiting when it happens?  MIDAS is setting up signal handlers for SIGALRM and SIGINT, and possibly SIGCHLD and SIGCONT

Comment: @thegreatemu - Fair enough. Just wanted to let you know about one potential solution to the problem that I saw. :-) Good luck.

Comment: @thegreatemu Well, that's how I interpret `<signal handler called>` at frame 7. You could try to [`SIG_BLOCK`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask) everything before calling the midas idle loop.

Comment: Did you figure out how to handle this?

Comment: @SuryaSharma Kind of.  I found that if I initialize things in exactly the right order, none of the critical signals are stolen from each other, except that I have to manually emulate a timing loop that was being handled by `SIGALRM`.  It's pretty far from stable, though.

Comment: I realized that I was defining the PylonAutoInitTerm object after defining a CInstantCamera and that was causing a crash. The AutoInitTerm object should come first.